# OSX: How to backup personal data via CLI script or command

Tags: terminal, backup, time-machine, command-line, single-user

I need run a backup of the personal data from my MacBook Pro (native HDD) to an external HDD.

I have used this external drive to back up this internal drive previously via Time Machine.

I don't have GUI access due to an internal problem, but I have mounted the file system using the "single user mode" command line interface.

Comment: I don't think this will work in single-user mode, but it is worth a shot.  `/usr/bin/tmutil startbackup` would be the simplest way to refresh the time machine backup.

Comment: Use the `rsync` command.

Comment: I second the rsync idea, see: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14754/rsync-backup-script?rq=1

Comment: Cheers. Never used `tmutil` before. Why don't you think it'll work in single-user mode? I'll try it. I think it's the backend to the GUI application I've been using. If it's no good, I'll try `rsync`.

Comment: So, did tmutil work in single-user mode? Did you succeed with your goal? Either way, please answer your own question as others may have the same question (being in single-user mode or not).